# Activate OLAP-Tools What-if-analysis

Tags: excel, vba

I found the vba-command to do a write-back-operation for changed pivottable-cells:

```
Pivot.AllocateChanges
```

Before publishing the changes the user manually needs to activate the what-if-analyse at the OLAP-Tools:

[image]

Is there a vba-command to automatically enable the what-if-analyse?
I took a look at the official documentation but i didnt find the neccessary method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivottable_members.aspx

Comment: What happens if you record a macro with these steps?

Comment: Oh didnt know about this possibility. Thank you! Please write it as answer so i can accept it as correct.

Comment: It would be more useful if you write the code that you have generated from the macro recorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neccessary command was visible while recording a macro. It is

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").EnableWriteback = True
```